# Pb for installing SQL Server Express Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Each time I launch the install, it launches the SQL Server Express 2008 panel instead of Management Studio why ?

Comment: Do as Seba Illingworth tells you to do below. After 6 hourse consecutive work - it finally works!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I just need to vent little bit and add myself to the list of angry users.
Why they went ahead and messed up the SQL installer is beyond me.

Took me 1+ hour to install SSMS because TO ADD A FEATURE you must select PERFORM A NEW INSTALLATION  grrr....

Anyway, a  good step-by-step with images (that saved my day) can be found http://www.asql.biz/Articoli/SQLX08/Art3_1.aspx#SSMSonSQLX

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the same steps when installing Studio Express as you would to install Sql Express (or a new instance of):

Installation > New Sql Server standalone... > click OK/NEXT until you're sick of it > Perform a new installation of.... > OK/NEXT a few more times > and there it is, "Management Tools - Basic"!

MS recommended best practices installer workflow (ya know, MSRBPIWF ;)

Comment: Hahaha! Actually you are correct. I had to continue install four times, before the management tools were visible. Thus far, I've worked with this install in 6 hours consecutive. The thing that made it - was to delete the MSSqlExpress install package, and then dbl-click the MSSqlServerMgt Studio 2008. Love it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Installation -> New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation -> Add features to an existing instance. If You downloaded Management Studio installation, you'll have option with it. It is really dumb that You have to do it this way, but that is how it works:)

Comment: I'm trying it right, it makes me crazy ! They have become worst than Oracle Install !

Comment: Well it still doesn't work for me : it only list SDK to install :(

Comment: Did you download installation version from here?

http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b#Requirements

Some of installation packages doesn't contain Management Studio.

Comment: Yes I donwloaded from here but how can it be since the title of the page is Management Studio Express 2008 ?!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is weird and I think the whole installation needs to be re done, (im having my own issues with it right now!)

I just installed management studio express on top of my SQL express 2008 installation and I had to do it by selecting a new installation / instance at the selection screen. If you select modify a existing installation, it only shows the components already installed.

When you do this, it only installs the management studio - nothing else despite it looking like it will from the selection screen.

Comment: +1 This allowed me to install ssms..thank you. I found this to be an accurate resolution using the current installer.  Also, I would like to also agree with other users that this installer is terrible and needs reworked.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you've not installed all the components n driver it requires, have you?

Comment: I have installed everything as mentioned in prerequisites
http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b#Requirements
In fact just before I installed sql server xpress 2008 with success so I can't see what