# Can SQL Server Management Studio 2005 work with SQL Server Express 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting crazy trying to install SQL Server Express Management Studio 2008
[Pb for installing SQL Server Express Management Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583545/pb-for-installing-sql-server-express-management-studio-2008/1583669#1583669)

I have tried 10 times, now I give up. But maybe I can try to work with SQL Server Management Studio 2005? Do you know if it will work?

Comment: Nope.  The Sql2k8 install experience definitely isn't the best one evar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use the full SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (included in SQL Server 2008 editions other than Express), and it can connect to SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 Express, and any of the 2005 (and even 2000) versions, but it doesn't work the other way around, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know it doesn't. You will get a message that says it will work with only SQL Server 2005 or later.